# WinPhone шаблоны приложений и ориентация устройства

Tags: c#, windowsphone, xaml, visual-studio

В VS13/15 есть несколько базовых шаблонов WP приложений: Пустое, Pivot и Hub.

Пустое и Pivot по умолчанию реагируют на изменение ориентации устройства (книжная/альбомная). Hub же не реагирует (в конструкторе вертится, а вот при запуске на устройстве/эмуляторе нет).

Собственно вопрос: почему и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пересмотрел ещё раз код, генерируемый шаблоном, и нашёл в `HubPage.xaml.cs` следующую строчку:

```
// Элемент управления Hub ("Главный раздел") поддерживается только в книжной ориентации
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```

Если её закомментировать - будет работать поворот. Но ощутимо подтормаживает. Собственно по этой причине и не поддерживается, скорее всего, по умолчанию.